# 'set' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following python code:

```
text = "this’s a sent tokenize test. this is sent two. is this sent three? sent 4 is cool! Now it’s your turn."
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
sent_tokenize_list = sent_tokenize(text)

import numpy as np

lenDoc=len(sent_tokenize_list)

features={'position','rate'}
score = np.empty((lenDoc, 2), dtype=object)
score=[[0 for x in range(sent_tokenize_list)] for y in range(features)]
for i,sentence in enumerate(sent_tokenize_list):
    score[i,features].append((lenDoc-i)/lenDoc)
```

But it results in the following error:

```
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-27-c53da2b2ab02> in <module>()
      13 
      14 
 ---> 15 score=[[0 for x in range(sent_tokenize_list)] for y in range(features)]
      16 for i,sentence in enumerate(sent_tokenize_list):
      17     score[i,features].append((lenDoc-i)/lenDoc)

 TypeError: 'set' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 1):

`range()` takes int values. `features` is a set so it throws an error. you made the same mistake with `range(sent_tokenize_list)`. `sent_tokenize_list` is a list value not an int.
If you want x and y to be indexes of `features` and `sent_tokenize_list` then you have to use this: `score=[[0 for x in range(len(sent_tokenize_list))] for y in range(len(features))]`
But if you want x and y to be values of `features` and `sent_tokenize_list` then you have to remove `range()` from that line.